# PreparedStatement fetch_assoc() doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get an array of x amount of data using PreparedStatements and fetch_assoc(). It doesn't return anything. Here's the code:

```php
if(isset($query_published) && isset($query_date) && isset($query_sort) && isset($query_rows)){
//Does meet the requirements

    $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT source, title, timeadded, tags, filed, added, priority, timepublished 
                                        FROM news_archive WHERE ? AND ? ORDER BY ? LIMIT ?");
    $stmt -> bind_param('sssi', $query_date, $query_published, $query_sort, $query_rows);
    //is valid, It's String, String, String, and an Integer.

    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt -> get_result();

    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        //Doesn't run this loop at all.
        $return .= "<tr>";
        $return .= "<td>" . $row["source"] . "</td>";
        $return .= "<td>" . $row["title"] . "</td>";
        $return .= "<td>" . $row["timeadded"] . "</td>";
        $return .= "<td>" . $row["timepublished"] . "</td>";
        $return .= "<td>" . $row["filed"] . "</td>";
        $return .= "</tr>";
        }
    $db -> close();

    }
```

I've verified it's not a MySQL problem, since I can run regular queries just fine. I tried printing out the parameters such as `$query_date, $query_published, $query_sort, $query_rows` before execution, and they are legitimate values.

The query is fine too. I filled the question marks with the parameters, and ran it on MySQL, is a valid query.

Comment: have you an example for $query_date?

Comment: @nbk Here are the defaults: ```$query_date = "timeadded > DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))```, ```$query_sort = timeadded DESC```, ```$query_published_crit = "(added IS NULL OR added IS NOT NULL)"``` (I know this isn't optimal, but for the sake of filling out the PreparedStatement), ```$query_rows = 20 ```

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro How? Doesn't `"sssi"` mean `String, String, String, Integer`, corresponding to the 4 vars?

Comment: bind_param() is not to bind a complete condition, only for the parameter values.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Then do you recommend I don't use a preparedstatements? What method should I use to bind params?

Comment: Please take a look in the mysql logs and see, what exactly reaches the server. that usualy give a hint.

Comment: I would recommend some db tutorials which show how its done correctly. example: "WHERE ?" is syntactically ok when binding a value to it. But "WHERE 5" is probably not what you wanted...